# unable to create Drupal user via java client using xml rpc

Tags: java, drupal, xml-rpc

I have this code to create a user, inspired by [this](http://drupal.org/node/632844).
After executing I have this error:

> An error occurred when attempting to create a new user
>   Username field is required.
>   E-mail address field is required.
>   Password field is required.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Username field is required.
>   E-mail address field is required.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean createUser(DrupalAccount account) throws Exception
{
    Vector<Object> params = generateDefaultParams(MethodUserCreate);
    // code can be re-factored to use ArrayList<Object>
    //ArrayList<Object> params = generateDefaultParams(MethodUserCreate);
    // must also re-factor generateDefaultParams method
    // currently objects don't work for submitting parameters to the
    // user.save service. Use an array instead

    params.add(account);
    try
    {
        Object o = xmlRpcClient.execute(MethodUserCreate, params);
        if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST))
        {
            log.finest(MethodUserCreate + " returned " + o.toString());
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("An error occurred when attempting to create a user");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    //TODO add code to inform if user successfully created
    return true;
}
```

---

**Edit:** I tried MathRo's suggestion and it still gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException:
Server error. Requested method user.create not specified.
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
    at DrupalService.userCreate(DrupalService.java:284)
    at Main.main(Main.java:29)
```

although I added in my Service class this:

```
public HashMap userCreate(String name, String mail, String pass)
        throws XmlRpcException {
    HashMap paramUser = new HashMap();
    paramUser.put("name", name);
    paramUser.put("mail",mail);
    paramUser.put("pass",pass);
    Object[] param = {paramUser};
    HashMap ret_createUser = (HashMap)xmlRpcClient.execute("user.create", param);
    return  ret_createUser;
}
```

and in my Main class this:

```
service.userCreate("myname", "me@mydomain.com", "mypass");
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm doing the same kind of work but not exactly like you. May I can help, but before can you tell more about your configuration ? using Drupal 7, Services 3, Apache XMLRPC for the JavaClient ? The main difference with my code, is that when I log to my Drupal site, I keep the session ID and the session Name, then I write it in the header to have the cookies session. With this I have the permission to create node (because the account logged have the permission...) P.S : Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: thank you drupal-6.20 services-6.x-2.4. apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3 my code is the same as the one in [this](http://drupal.org/node/632844) I just made some changes. I put a username, password, email address but it gives me this error `An error occurred when attempting to create a new user Username field is required. E-mail address field is required. Password field is required. Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Username field is required. E-mail address field is required.`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not used to Drupal 6 and services-6 but I'll try to help (I'm working with D7).

Did you try to call the *user.save* method by creating the parameter yourself (without using the DruaplAccount Object)?

For example for my JavaClient (with services 3.x on D7), I made a function to create a user:

```
/**
 * Create a user 
 * @param name : 
 * @param mail
 * @param pass
 * @return
 * @throws XmlRpcException
 */
public HashMap userCreate(String name, String mail, String pass)
        throws XmlRpcException {
    HashMap paramUser = new HashMap();
    paramUser.put("name", name);
    paramUser.put("mail",mail);
    paramUser.put("pass",pass);
    Object[] param = {paramUser};
    HashMap ret_createUser =
            (HashMap) this.client.execute("user.create", param );
    return  ret_createUser;
}
```

I don't know if it's very helpful, but I posted in case it could.

Comment: This suggestion is for the module services 7.x-3.x-dev. In your case your using services 6.x-2.4, so I looked in the code and the name of the method for the 6.x-2.4 version is "user.save", not "user.create". So you have to replace  _this.client.execute("user.create", param )_ by _this.client.execute("user.save", param );_.