# User register code

Tags: android, drupal, drupal-7

```
 //create a new HttpClient and post header
    HttpClient httpClient   =   new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost       =   new HttpPost("http://test.site.com/testpoint/user/register");

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try{
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs  =   new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[pass]", "cutelady"));
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[mail]", "scarter@sgc.gov"));
    nameValuePairs.add( new BasicNameValuePair("account[name]", "Samantha Carter"));
    httpPost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    //Execute HTTP post request
    HttpResponse response   =   httpClient.execute(httpPost);

}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("HTTP ERROR", e.toString());
}
```

I have tried this code on xml rpc module of drupal on android. I cannot succeed it. Is it xml rpc or json function? Which one is for? Then, could you give me the url path to send it so that drupal can accept it. I cannot understand "http://test.site.com/testpoint/user/register" path meaning. Do you know it? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the xml you need to send in order to register a user:

https://drupal.org/node/1299978

Since you are using java you might have some luck looking at this post as well:

[unable to create Drupal user via java client using xml rpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899814/unable-to-create-drupal-user-via-java-client-using-xml-rpc)

Comment: You are my angel. This is what I want. I got luck from you. Thank you.

Comment: If I add extra field as integer or boolean in drupal, how can I send from android?